# did cmd change in Windows 7, how to undo?

Tags: windows-7, command-line, undo

Windows 7 was not allowing me to add a new folder within folders.  So I made the command prompt change using the icacls command below. This includes 'desktop', which included all the shortcut icons. Every folder and icon on the desktop was shown in the results, so I know it affected each. One of these icons is Compuhost, a karaoke hosting program. Since I made the cmd change, can't get Compuhost to work properly. How do I undo the change for Compuhost shortcut? The command I used was:

```
icacls C:\Users\USERNAME\Desktop /grant USERNAME:f /t
```

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't expect that the problem is caused by what you think.  Full control is not likely to introduce negative consequences in that way.  Typically, a non-administrator user will basically have full control over his Desktop files anyway - unless explicitly revoked (which would not apply to Karaoke app).

I would recommend checking your event log and seeing what's the cause of the error, and if nothing there, try running it in compatability mode.

The command you ran doesn't seem like it could possibly be the source of your problem.

However, if you want to change, heres how:

In general, changing acls for a single file is easier with the GUI.  Right click; select properties.  Go to Security Tab.  You can make all changes there.

Answer (score -2):

Remove the `/t`

if YOU ARE.. using the "USERNAME" as the username target, replace it w/ your proper username, otherwise you'll get an error of `no mapping`.

In case of error, tell me what it said.